# Stream stdin to a Wai.EventSource

Tags: haskell, haskell-wai, haskell-warp

I would like to stream stdin over an HTTP connection using `text/event-stream`. The [Network.Wai.EventSource](http://haddock.stackage.org/lts-5.15/wai-extra-3.0.15.1/Network-Wai-EventSource.html) thing looks like a good candidate.

I tried using this code:

```
import Network.Wai
import Network.Wai.EventSource
import Network.Wai.Middleware.AddHeaders
import Network.Wai.Handler.Warp (run)
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as L
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8 as C
import Blaze.ByteString.Builder.ByteString

toEvent :: [L.ByteString] -> ServerEvent
toEvent s = ServerEvent {
    eventName = Nothing,
    eventId = Nothing,
    eventData = map fromLazyByteString s
}

createWaiApp :: IO L.ByteString -> Application
createWaiApp input = eventSourceAppIO $ fmap (toEvent . C.lines) input

main :: IO ()
main = run 1337 $ createWaiApp L.getContents
```

Which (I think) does:

- Reads stdin as a Lazy ByteStream
- Splits the ByteStream into lines
- Produces one ServerEvent for all the lines (this feels wrong - there should presumably be multiple events?)
- Builds a WAI Application from the `IO ServerEvent`
- Binds the Application to port 1337

When I run this (e.g. using `ping -c 5 example.com | stack exec test-exe`) it doesn't respond until the whole of stdin has been read.

How do I build a Wai application that flushes out the HTTP connection every time it reads a *line* from stdin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`L.getContents` is a single IO action, so only one event will be created.

Here is an example of eventSourcEventAppIO where multiple events are created:

```
import Blaze.ByteString.Builder.Char8 (fromString)
...same imports as above...

nextEvent :: IO ServerEvent
nextEvent = do
  s <- getLine
  let event = if s == ""
                then CloseEvent
                else ServerEvent
                     { eventName = Nothing
                     , eventId = Nothing
                     , eventData = [ fromString s ]
                     }
  case event of
    CloseEvent ->     putStrLn "<close event>"
    ServerEvent _ _ _ -> putStrLn "<server event>"
  return event

main :: IO ()
main = run 1337 $ eventSourceAppIO nextEvent
```

To test, in one window start up the server and in another run the command `curl -v http://localhost:1337`. For each line you enter in the server window you will get a data frame from curl. Entering a blank line will close the HTTP connection but the server will remain running allowing you to connect to it again.